# Indexing an object in php syntax

Tags: php, slim

When I read the slim source code to see this with code

```
$this['settings'] = function () use ($userSettings, $defaultSettings) {
        return new Collection(array_merge($defaultSettings, $userSettings));
    };
```

Why ‘$this’ can be enclosed in brackets
What is this grammar?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation for Slim?

Answer (score 2):

Any class that implements the [ArrayAccess](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface can use the `[]` operator as implemented